# Iterate over one index of a python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, key, iteration

I have a python dictionary called `lines`, which is indexed by tuples, such as: `('mid', 'north')`, `('south', 'mid')` and `('south', 'north')`.

```
lines = {('mid', 'north'): None,
         ('south', 'mid'): None,
         ('south', 'north'): None,
        }
```

I create a variable(`l_key`) to make tuples from the keys of `lines` dict.

```
l_key = tuple(lines.keys())
i = 0
```

Then I am iterating over the dictionary keys via `lines.keys()`:

```
for line in lines.keys():
    lines[line] = Line(l_key[i][0], l_key[i][1])
    i += 1
```

Here is the problem, as I want first string of the first key of the `lines` inside `class Line`, I have to index `l_key` with `[i][0]`, and at first iteration `i=0`, I get `'mid'`.

Then at the second iteration `i=1`, and I get `'south'` from `l_key[1][0]`.

I would like to know if there is a way me to remove `i=0` and `i+=1`, from the for-loop and create somehow the same effect?

EG:

```
for line in lines.keys() and i in range(0, len(l_key):
    lines[line] = Line(l_key[i][0], l_key[i][1])
```

If I do above version, it will probably run 3 times for `lines.keys()` and 3 for `range(0, len(l_key)`. So 3x3=9 times... What I need is to run this for-loop over `lines.keys()` and increase the `i` value at every iteration.

doing below works, but is there a better way?:

```
i = 0
for line in lines.keys():
    lines[line] = Line(l_key[i][0], l_key[i][1])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `lines.keys()`, as `for` loops iterates *automatically by keys*:

```
for line in lines:
    lines[line] = Line(line[0], line[1])
```

As you can see, it's all - you don't need any index (`i`) for keys.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(lines.keys()):
        lines[line] = Line(l_key[i][0], l_key[i][1])
```

Comment: Sorry, I did firstly accept this answer, it is actually working and nice. But as @MarianD mentioned. There is still a better way :(